# Sending AWS credentials to clients

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Are there any security risks when sending AWS access key + secret to clients, so they can make operations on s3 such as list objects and write objects? The clients i'm referring to are web, android and iOS.

I know there is a way to generate dynamic credentials for 2 hours, so I don't worry about the clients having access for eternity.

Comment: Question is not clear. How do you send the credentials and how do the "clients" use them?

Answer (score 3):

You are not supposed to expose the access key and secret key to public. Since its in web its easy to open up the files in browser developer tools and find out and its total disaster in doing it even though its an IAM user with fully restricted policies on AWS resources.

For dyanamic credentials checkout the IAM roles concept where the AWS STS takes care of the rotation of the keys and in roles you dont need to share any credentials.

For mobile clients check for https://aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdk/